# Exploded jar in war libs

Tags: java, jboss

Can we put exploded jar files in war web-inf libs ? Its not working for me in JBOSS 4.2. I got following error and not able to deploy the application:

```
Caused by: javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method init
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:304)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployer.java:301)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.TomcatDeployer.performDeploy(TomcatDeployer.java:104)
        at org.jboss.web.AbstractWebDeployer.start(AbstractWebDeployer.java:375)
        ... 113 more
Caused by: javax.management.RuntimeOperationsException: Exception invoking method addChild
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:304)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.RawDynamicInvoker.invoke(RawDynamicInvoker.java:164)
        at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:659)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.init(StandardContext.java:5312)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:296)
        ... 118 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext
        at org.apache.catalina.util.ExtensionValidator.validateApplication(ExtensionValidator.java:182)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:790)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:770)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:553)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:296)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you unpack a jar-file the resulting files needs to go into `WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: Even If I copy jar file in WEB-INF/classes folder its not working..it gives class not found excpetion..having class files direclty will work any day..

Comment: Make sure you preserve the directory structure. E.g. For class `com.foo.bar.MyClass` it needs to be found under: `WEB-INF/classes/com/foo/bar/MyClass.class`

Comment: I have kept the directory structure same..but its inside one directory with .jar extenstion..

Comment: That won't work. It needs to be exactly as in my example, i.e. the `com` in `com.foo.bar.MyClass` must be immediately under `WEB-INF/classes`.

Answer (score 0):

Not in `WEB-INF/lib`.

Try `WEB-INF/classes`.